# Problema al instalar paquete nuget

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm, nuget

estoy trabjando con MVVMCross y Xamarin.Android. Y parece que para cierta función (hacer un binding de Mvx.MvxImageView) necesito instalar el paquete MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache.

Al intentar instalarlo me devuelve el siguiente error:

> No se pudo instalar el paquete 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
>   27.0.2'.  Está intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene  'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0' como destino, pero el paquete no
>   contiene  referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido
>   compatibles con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en
>   contacto con el autor del paquete.

Intentando instalar el paquete 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2 de forma manual también me da ese error.

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es porque este paquete depende de Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat y en el proyecto android tienes referenciada una librería **`Mono.Android.dll`** con la versión 5.0 y no son compatibles.

[image: monoandroid]

Tendrías que saber si el paquete que necesitas tiene una versión inferior que no use Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat o soporta alguna otra versión en que el paquete Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat sea compatible con tu MonoAndroid.

En el paquete nuget `MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache` navega hasta abajo y verás el apartado **Dependencias** mira que tengas las dependencias en tu proyecto y sean compatibles.

[image: dependencias]

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. No hay versiones de Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat compatibles con Mono Android v5.¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Actualiza tu versión MonoAndroid, por ejemplo la 8.0 sí la soporta. Si en la respuesta he resuelto tu pregunta no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta, gracias.